# Swift Package Resolution Failed: artifact of binary target failed download: invalid status code 401

Tags: ios, swift-package-manager

I am using xcode12.2 and swift 5.3. I tried the same on 12.5 and swift 5.4. But having the similar issue while trying to add my package from my github repo.

[image]

I also tried, ssh but this time it fails at first line giving fingerprint error.

[image]

pls help here, if anyone knows what's wrong here.

Comment: Is your repository **Private**?  Let's see your `Package.swift` file.